# R dplyr::mutate - add all elements in a returned list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function returning a list.  I'm using `mutate` to add columns in a data frame that correspond to the output.  The calculation is rather involved so I would prefer to only call the function once.  I'm rather new to R and dplry and cannot figure out a more efficient way of doing this.

Here is a very simple example of what I am doing now.

```
library(dplyr)

testFun <- function(x,z)
{
  list(x2=x*x + z, x3=x*x*x + z)
}

have <- data.frame(x=seq(1:10),y=1,z=0)

want <- have %>%
        dplyr::mutate(x2=testFun(x,z)$x2,
                      x3=testFun(x,z)$x3)
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
pmap_dfr(have %>% 
              select(x, z), testFun) %>%
   bind_cols(have, .)
#    x y z  x2   x3
#1   1 1 0   1    1
#2   2 1 0   4    8
#3   3 1 0   9   27
#4   4 1 0  16   64
#5   5 1 0  25  125
#6   6 1 0  36  216
#7   7 1 0  49  343
#8   8 1 0  64  512
#9   9 1 0  81  729
#10 10 1 0 100 1000
```

---

Or if we can change the function by quoting (`quote` or `quo`) it, this becomes more easier

```
testFun <- function(x,z){
  list(x2= quo(x*x + z), x3= quo(x*x*x + z))
 }

have %>% 
   mutate(!!! testFun(x, z))
#    x y z  x2   x3
#1   1 1 0   1    1
#2   2 1 0   4    8
#3   3 1 0   9   27
#4   4 1 0  16   64
#5   5 1 0  25  125
#6   6 1 0  36  216
#7   7 1 0  49  343
#8   8 1 0  64  512
#9   9 1 0  81  729
#10 10 1 0 100 1000
```

Comment: thanks.  the `quote()` won't work in the real code because it's rather complex.  The only thing I needed to add to the first part is a `rename()` because the variables on the input frame differ slightly from the function variable names.

Answer (score 7):

With the `purrr`-package you can solve this problem, like that:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

testFun <- function(x,z) {
  tibble(x2=x*x + z, x3=x*x*x + z)
}

have %>%
  mutate(new_x = map2(x, z, testFun)) %>% 
  unnest(new_x)

#     x y z  x2   x3
# 1   1 1 0   1    1
# 2   2 1 0   4    8
# 3   3 1 0   9   27
# 4   4 1 0  16   64
# 5   5 1 0  25  125
# 6   6 1 0  36  216
# 7   7 1 0  49  343
# 8   8 1 0  64  512
# 9   9 1 0  81  729
# 10 10 1 0 100 1000
```

Note that I changed the output of your function from a list to a tibble.

Answer (score 2):

I might have missed something really obvious here, but you seem to be running the function twice to produce two answers. To keep things really simple to begin with, try:

```
library(dplyr)

have <- data.frame(x=seq(1:10),y=1,z=0)

want <- have %>%
        dplyr::mutate(x2 = (x * 2 + z),
                      x3 = (x * 3 + z))
```

Does that help? Or has your example simplified out what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks.  the function is extremely involved and needs to be abstracted away from the mutate call.

Answer (score 1):

Using a different function for the mutate you should be able to do:

```
library(dplyr)

createMultiX <- function(inputX, inputZ, multiplier) {
  inputX * multiplier + inputZ
}


have <- data.frame(x=seq(1:10),y=1,z=0)

want <- have %>%
        dplyr::mutate(x2 = createMultiX(x, z, 2),
                      x3 = createMultiX(x, z, 3))
```

(Apologies in advance as I've written this blindly without access to an R terminal so hope it works first time without typos!)

Comment: Actually for speed I'd also replace data.frame with tibble (from the tibble package) - they are tidied data frames so should be quicker. Literally just replace data.frame() with tibble()

Comment: the real function in my code is much more complex than the simple example given.  This won't work.  Thank you though.

Comment: In what way is it different? Could you phrase your example in such a way that I can get what the issue is with a more complex scenario? That might help to create a solution.